# Reading an image in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, imread

I am trying to import an image in python to later use it in a plot. I am using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.image as image
im = image.imread('image.png')
```

And I am having the following error:

> SystemError:  built-in method fileno of _io.FileIO object at 0x00000295A8277750 returned a result with an error set

The image exist in the current folder. I tried also the following with the same result:

```
from matplotlib._png import read_png
png_file = open('image.png')
Image = read_png(png_file)
```

Error output:

> SystemError: built-in method fileno of _io.FileIO object at 0x00000295A8277828 returned a result with an error set

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you preview your image with any image viewing software?

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. It seems that when I was downloading a png file from internet I wasn't  saving it as `image.png` but as `image` (When saving as `image` windows still 'says' that the file is in png format). And this caused the problem above.

Comment: Deactivating the hiding of file extensions is the very first thing I do on every windows system I use.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your directory is wrong.
I tried this code and worked.

```
import matplotlib.image as image

imgg = image.imread('/home/ss/Desktop/1.jpg')
plt.imshow(imgg)
plt.show()
```